# Не могу подключиться по ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что я выставил для всех пользователей одинаковый пароль на одной и второй машине, чтобы наверняка получилось и в настройках Виртуальной машины сеть поставил: Сетевой мост. Он не хочет подключаться. Не понимаю, что надо сделать?
sshd_config:

```
Port 22

Protocol 2,1

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

KeyRegenerationInterval lh
ServerKeyBits 1024


SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes



IgnoreRhosts yes

RhostsRSAAuthentication no

HostbasedAuthentication no

IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

PermitEmptyPasswords no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

PasswordAuthentication yes


X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
UseLogin no

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

UsePAM yes
```

P.S. Добавил логи машины, к которой подключаюсь
P.P.S Ошибка запуска ssh - `ubuntu@ubutnu:~$ service ssh start` => Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: Во-первых, не надо подключаться суперпользователем, а во-вторых, скорее всего этот метод входа запрещён в глобальном конфигурационном файле. `PermitRootLogin yes`.

Comment: @0andriy всё равно не хочет

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: 1. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` — это с той машины, к которой подключаетесь? 2. *sshd* перезапускали после внесения изменений в этот файл? 3. приведите в тексте вопроса строки, которые добавляются во время попытки подключения в файл `/var/log/auth.log` на той машине, к которой подключаетесь.

Comment: Сделай `Protocol 2`. Никто не использует 1-ю версию.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin 1 - это на обеих. Пытался перезапустить и вот, что пишет: "ubuntu@ubutnu:~$ service ssh start
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

Comment: @donRumata я поставил и первый, чтобы оно вообще заработало, в любом случае

Comment: Ну хрен ли мелочиться, втыкай тогда и `telnet`. Хрен ли там. Гулять - так гулять.

Comment: @don_Rumata 1й протокол исподьзуют очень много роутеров и сетевых экранов (Cisco, SonicWall) в промышлености, банковских сетях, кино индустрии и других маштабных комеоческих сетях. Связано это с большими рассходами по смене всей ифроструктуры. Из опыта помню ящики DIGITAL,  компании поглащенной HP,  так их сервера не снимают из сети уже более 30лет. telnet тоже в многих роутерах присуствует - ZyXEL например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как можно сделать вывод из первого скрина, где белым по красному (: написано,
что модуль **pam** не принял авторизацию пользователя с UID=0.

> Description : PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) is a system security tool that
>               : allows system administrators to set authentication policy without
>               : having to recompile programs that handle authentication.

Приведу тесты, проведенные на Fedora 24:

Собираем информацию о системе и пакетах.

```
server:~# uname -sr
Linux 4.11.6-101.fc24.x86_64

server:~# lsb_release -d
Description:    Fedora release 24 (Twenty Four)

server:~# rpm -qf $(which "sshd")
openssh-server-7.2p2-14.fc24.x86_64

server:~# rpm -qf $(which "openssl")
openssl-1.0.2k-1.fc24.x86_64

server:~# rpm -qf $(which "ssh-keygen")
openssh-7.2p2-14.fc24.x86_64

server:~# rpm -qf $(which "pam_console_apply")
pam-1.2.1-5.fc24.x86_64
```

Следующий шаг проверяем, что у нас в конфигурации:

```
server:~# grep -v "\#\|^$" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PermitRootLogin yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Ключевым здесь является опция *UsePAM yes*, что отсылает нас к проверке
настройки **pam**

```
server:~# grep -v "\#\|^$"  /etc/pam.d/sshd
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```

Дальнейший виток приводит к чтению описаний самих модулей pam.

Проведем минимальное тестирование всех конфигов убедившись, что в них нет ошибок.

```
server:~# sshd -t
server:~# echo $?
0

server:~# pamtester sshd root open_session
pamtester: sucessfully opened a session
```

Так же посоветовал бы определится с авторизацией - это ключи или пароли?  Жестко
прописать это в конфигурации, авторизацию root пользователя желательно пресечь.

В пользовательских конфигурациях так же жестко пропишите тип авторизации - ключ
или пароль. Если ключ, то прямую ссылку к нему так же желательно добавить.

```
host:~$ cat ~/.ssh/config
HashKnownHosts yes

Host bitbucket.org
    User git
    HostName bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bibucket_home_rsa
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Ссылки

- http://pamtester.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.linux-pam.org/
- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Guidelines/OpenSSH

Comment: Т.е. Нужно сгенерировать все ключи на обеих машинах и можно юзать пам?

Comment: @kot_mapku3. прочтите про модули которые у вас активны для /etc/pam.d/sshd